# How to get actual style of text in word document using python docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am using python docx library to read **MS word** file(.docx). When i read paragraph i use font function to get all style properties. But sometimes it gives **None** for font size attribute. Is there any way to get actual font size which paragraph contains.
Example code is given below which i am using to parse paragraphs

```
from docx import Document
d = Document(document_path)
for paragraph in d.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        print (run.font.size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. What you're asking for is *effective* font size and `python-docx` can only see an explicitly set font size. When `font.size` reports None, it is the default for that paragraph, whatever that is, which depends on the style hierarchy.

In many cases it might be the font size of the applicable paragraph style, but the only way to know for sure is to traverse the style hierarchy for that text node to the first explicit definition.

Comment: Thanks Scanny, I just iterate through all runs for the paragraph and check for size if available.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me:

Divide it by 12700 to get actually font size.

```
import docx
docFile = docx.Document("C:/Users/vjadhav6/Desktop/testFile.docx")
for i in docFile.paragraphs:
    for j in i.runs:
        print(j.font.size/12700)
```

Comment: Yes, what if **j.font.size** returns None. I was looking for the font size instead of None. scanny has explained in his response below.