# No access to the attributes of styles in MS-Word files when default style is used, using python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm using the python-docx library to work on Microsoft Word .docx files.
The global purpose is to know what is the style attributes of paragraphs and runs in order to count the lines for each different style. Most of the time it works, but sometimes certain attributes are in a 'None' state, I guess that it is when the Word-user uses Default Templates...

Here an example (only with the font-name attribute), tested on a word document 'text.docx' that uses 'Calibri Light' font, but all what I get is 'None' for all Paragraphs and Runs :

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('text.docx')
for par_number, par in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
    print('Paragraph', par_number, ':', par.style.font.name)
    for run_number, run in enumerate(par.runs):
        print('    Run', run_number, ':', run.font.name)
```

Output :

```
Paragraph 0 : None
    Run 0 : None
Paragraph 1 : None
Paragraph 2 : None
    Run 0 : None
Paragraph 3 : None
    Run 0 : None
Paragraph 4 : None
    Run 0 : None
```

Is there a way to know what font name is actually used, at higher level than paragraphs, or even if it is embedded somewhere in Word ? thanks !

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "effective" font name. Word has a style hierarchy like CSS where these things are inherited if not specified (`None`). See this post for a little more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59623376/1902513

Comment: Thanks @scanny, i'll try to understand how to search throw the styles.

Answer (score 2):

The font name might be stored in a theme, but `python-docx` does not seem to support themes in its current version.

DOCX are ZIP files with some XML  files inside and `python-docx` can be used to query that XML if you know where to look.

I used a document with two paragraphs and one run in each paragraph. The first paragraph has the default font and I changed the second paragraph font to Arial:

[image: two-paragraphs]

You can always extract the XML files from a DOCX file with any ZIP file manager. The following fragments of the XML files show the default document configuration for paragraphs and runs in my test document and the theme configuration:

Fragment of `/word/styles.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:styles xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh">
    <w:docDefaults>
        <w:rPrDefault>
            <w:rPr>
                <!-- These are the references to the fonts of the theme -->
                <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi" />
                <w:sz w:val="22" />
                <w:szCs w:val="22" />
                <w:lang w:val="es-CO" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:bidi="ar-SA" />
            </w:rPr>
        </w:rPrDefault>
        <w:pPrDefault>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:spacing w:after="160" w:line="259" w:lineRule="auto" />
            </w:pPr>
        </w:pPrDefault>
    </w:docDefaults>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
</w:styles>
```

Fragment of `/word/theme/theme1.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a:theme xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" name="Tema de Office">
    <a:themeElements>
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
        <a:fontScheme name="Office">
            <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
            <a:minorFont>
                <!-- This seems to be the font -->
                <a:latin typeface="Calibri" panose="020F0502020204030204" />
                <a:ea typeface="" />
                <a:cs typeface="" />
                <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="游ゴシック Light" />
                <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
            </a:minorFont>
        </a:fontScheme>
        <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
    </a:themeElements>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
</a:theme>
```

This code shows how to obtain that font name using `python-docx`, [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and parsing the theme part of the package:

```python
from docx.oxml import parse_xml
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import serialize_for_reading
from docx.oxml.ns import nsmap, qn

# Here goes the code of the question

print()
print("rFonts elements in the document default properties for runs ('./w:docDefaults/w:rPrDefault/w:rPr'):")
print()
for fonts in doc.styles.element.xpath("./w:docDefaults/w:rPrDefault/w:rPr/w:rFonts"):
  print(fonts.xml)
  # Get the theme name (e.g. w:asciiTheme)
  print("asciiTheme:", fonts.attrib[qn("w:asciiTheme")])
  # minorHAnsi corresponds to a:minorFont in the themes

print()
# Iterate over the parts of the package
for part in doc.part.package.parts:
  # Use parts that start with "/word/theme/"
  if part.partname.startswith("/word/theme/"):
    print(f"Parsing theme {part.partname}")
    theme = parse_xml(part.blob)
    print()
    print("minorFont elements in the theme ('//a:minorFont'):")
    print()
    for minor_font in theme.xpath("//a:minorFont", namespaces=nsmap):
      print(serialize_for_reading(minor_font))
      # Get the typeface of the corresponding font (e.g. './a:latin/@typeface')
      for typeface in minor_font.xpath("./a:latin/@typeface", namespaces=nsmap):
        print("typeface:", typeface)
```

Output:

```
Paragraph 0 : None
    Run 0 : None
Paragraph 1 : None
    Run 0 : Arial

rFonts elements in the document default properties for runs ('./w:docDefaults/w:rPrDefault/w:rPr'):

<w:rFonts xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi"/>

asciiTheme: minorHAnsi

Parsing theme /word/theme/theme1.xml

minorFont elements in the theme ('//a:minorFont'):

<a:minorFont xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
  <a:latin typeface="Calibri" panose="020F0502020204030204"/>
  <a:ea typeface=""/>
  <a:cs typeface=""/>
  <a:font script="Jpan" typeface="游明朝"/>
  <a:font script="Hang" typeface="맑은 고딕"/>
  <a:font script="Hans" typeface="等线"/>
  <a:font script="Hant" typeface="新細明體"/>
  <a:font script="Arab" typeface="Arial"/>
  <a:font script="Hebr" typeface="Arial"/>
  <a:font script="Thai" typeface="Cordia New"/>
  <a:font script="Ethi" typeface="Nyala"/>
  <a:font script="Beng" typeface="Vrinda"/>
  <a:font script="Gujr" typeface="Shruti"/>
  <a:font script="Khmr" typeface="DaunPenh"/>
  <a:font script="Knda" typeface="Tunga"/>
  <a:font script="Guru" typeface="Raavi"/>
  <a:font script="Cans" typeface="Euphemia"/>
  <a:font script="Cher" typeface="Plantagenet Cherokee"/>
  <a:font script="Yiii" typeface="Microsoft Yi Baiti"/>
  <a:font script="Tibt" typeface="Microsoft Himalaya"/>
  <a:font script="Thaa" typeface="MV Boli"/>
  <a:font script="Deva" typeface="Mangal"/>
  <a:font script="Telu" typeface="Gautami"/>
  <a:font script="Taml" typeface="Latha"/>
  <a:font script="Syrc" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa"/>
  <a:font script="Orya" typeface="Kalinga"/>
  <a:font script="Mlym" typeface="Kartika"/>
  <a:font script="Laoo" typeface="DokChampa"/>
  <a:font script="Sinh" typeface="Iskoola Pota"/>
  <a:font script="Mong" typeface="Mongolian Baiti"/>
  <a:font script="Viet" typeface="Arial"/>
  <a:font script="Uigh" typeface="Microsoft Uighur"/>
  <a:font script="Geor" typeface="Sylfaen"/>
  <a:font script="Armn" typeface="Arial"/>
  <a:font script="Bugi" typeface="Leelawadee UI"/>
  <a:font script="Bopo" typeface="Microsoft JhengHei"/>
  <a:font script="Java" typeface="Javanese Text"/>
  <a:font script="Lisu" typeface="Segoe UI"/>
  <a:font script="Mymr" typeface="Myanmar Text"/>
  <a:font script="Nkoo" typeface="Ebrima"/>
  <a:font script="Olck" typeface="Nirmala UI"/>
  <a:font script="Osma" typeface="Ebrima"/>
  <a:font script="Phag" typeface="Phagspa"/>
  <a:font script="Syrn" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa"/>
  <a:font script="Syrj" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa"/>
  <a:font script="Syre" typeface="Estrangelo Edessa"/>
  <a:font script="Sora" typeface="Nirmala UI"/>
  <a:font script="Tale" typeface="Microsoft Tai Le"/>
  <a:font script="Talu" typeface="Microsoft New Tai Lue"/>
  <a:font script="Tfng" typeface="Ebrima"/>
</a:minorFont>

typeface: Calibri
```

[Demo in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qLPwpF0cc2ERGVwUyjF5jm8rtNp9Fqmy).

The Office Open XML file formats are described with all details in [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/).

Comment: Thanks @Hernán for your precise answer, I'll work on it to understanding what you wrote, I'm not familiar with XML and libraries attached to it, so I'll take a certain time... thanks  again !